# How to delete file(s) from a folder with ever changing name?

Tags: batch-file

Good day,

I am trying to delete a specific extension within a directory, however the directory in which this file is can be different.

For example:

```
del C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\todelete\*.txt
```

However, the directory "todelete" changes so I want the batch file to delete any *.txt from any directory on the desktop. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
del /s /q C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\*.txt
```

this will immediately delete **all** `*.txt` files in the `Desktop` folder recursively.
For more help enter `help dir`.

```
for /d %%a in ("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\*") do del /s /q "%%~a\*.txt"
```

this will delete **all** `*.txt` files in the subfolders of the `desktop` folder.

Comment: Thanks, I want to delete all text files under "todelete" which may also be any other folder name. I got the following: for /d %%A in (Z:\Program Files\_\*) do (del %%A\*.txt) however it has a problem with the space in "Program Files". Works with non spaced directories.

Answer (score 0):

Use the /s option on the del command:

```
cd c:\users\USERNAME\Desktop
del /s *.txt
```